# UIWebView & Javascript: accessing the parent div of the selection

Tags: javascript, html, styles, selection, parent

How can I change the parent div style of the selected text in a UIWebView? Using:

```
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startContainer.parentNode.style.textAlign=\"center\";" ]];
```

is OK when the parentNode is a div, but do not work, for instance, if the selected text is in a *...*  node.

Comment: Did you try using .parent or .parentElement intead of using .parentNode?

Comment: Yes, I suppose I need to put a loop, looking for parent element until it is a 'div'... I hoped that I could get a kind of parent('div') or parentDiv instruction...